# Align Button with Input

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4, alignment

I'm fairly new to web development and I've tried for hours to figure this out. I'm trying to align my button along with the input sections instead of the labels. I've tried to find a few solutions on StackOverflow but it doesn't seem to work.

In CSS I attempted to use margin-top and just push the button down to align with the input which I guess kinda works but there has to be a much easier/better way.

Here's my code (screenshots)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrSmg.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJkfr.png)

Comment: Hi Kevin. Welcome to SO. It would be helpful for others if you can provide us with editable code. Images are cool, but pasted code would be beneficial for all. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a label on submit then hide it.

P.S. Adding a label will also be good for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert "align-self-end" class to the last "col-md-3".

```
<div class=“col-md-3 align-self-end“>
    <button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! It unfortunately pushed the button down slightly past the inputs, but I'll definitely keep this mind for future use!

Answer (score 0):

You could use html Tables!

Check out this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) for more info.

Try This:

```
<form class="container-fluid py-3 m-O">
<h2 class="py-3">Want to sign up for our free monthly newsletter?</h2>
<div class="form-row">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <th>Last Name:</th> 
        <th>Email:</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-md btn-always-col">Submit!</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this!